# Option, in answers, to merge a user with OP

Tags: feature-request, moderation, merge-accounts

Thinking of ways to make a common task easier for moderators.

We've seen it a hundred times.  A cookie-based user asks a question.  Later, they log on from a different machine and cannot edit their question, so they add an answer to leave comments or add details.

A moderator has two choices.  They can delete the answer and move on, or...

1. The mod clicks on the OP user account and the second account
2. The mod copies the user number from the OP account, or from whichever is registered
3. The mod tabs over to the second account, clicks the Mod link, clicks merge
4. The mod pastes the master user ID into the form and submits.

I'd suggest the following...

From the mod menu on an answer, there is an option to merge the answer account with the OP account.

The UI provides the information we normally use to make this decision--the email addresses of both accounts and common IPs.  Visually inspecting these, the moderator can cancel out or accept the merge.

The process should automatically select OP as the target if both are unregistered or registered, and the registered account if one is registered and one is not.

The process should probably not work if either has a large rep; this is most likely going to be used on new users who don't understand the cookie based accounts.

Comment: The new suggested edits feature makes it a lot easier for new users to provide this data outside of a new answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't happen often enough...